# Oracle Apex Signature Plugin issue

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to create digital signature feature in apex application and was able to do via the plugin created exactly following steps mentioned here:

https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-apexsignature

I used this plugin directly and am able to sign .
However in the interactive grid query below, if i use the query below directly, it throws pl sql numeric conversion error:
I wish to get the report similar to the way its shown in demo application, but am unable to.
Also in interactive grid i cannot find option to set datatype for blob001 column. i want it to be downloadable link.

```
SELECT c001    AS filename,
       c002    AS mime_type,
       d001    AS date_created,
       blob001 AS img_content
  FROM apex_collections
 WHERE collection_name = 'APEX_SIGNATURE';
```

Apex 20.2

Answer (score 1):

The Demo application utilizes an Interactive Report, not Interactive Grid.
[image]

Probably that's the source of the error.